# For a given precision, what is the maximum value for which a float32 will give the same result as a float64?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-accuracy

With numpy, I'm trying to understand what is the maximum value that can be downcasted from float64 to float32 with a loss on accuracy less or equal to 0.001.

Since I could not find a simple explanation online, I quickly came up with this piece of code to test :

```
result = {}
for j in range(1,1000):
    for i in range (1, 1_000_000):
        num = i + j/1000
        x=np.array([num],dtype=np.float32)
        y=np.array([num],dtype=np.float64)
        if abs(x[0]-y[0]) > 0.001:
            result[j] = i
            break
```

Based on the results, it seems any positive value <32768 can be safely downcasted from float64 to float32 with an acceptable loss on accuracy (given the criteria of <=0.001)

Is this correct ?
Could someone explain the math behind ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: When converted from `float64` to `float32`, ∞ produces the same value with no loss of accuracy. So that is the maximum for the question as phrased in the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming IEEE 754 representation, [`float32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has a 24-bit significand precision, while [`float64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has a 53-bit significand precision (except for “denormal” numbers).

In order to represent a number with an absolute error of at most 0.001, you need at least 9 bits to the right of the binary point, which means the numbers are rounded off to the nearest multiple of 1/512, thus having a maximum representation error of 1/1024 = 0.0009765625 < 0.001.

With 24 significant bits in total, and 9 to the right of the binary point, that leaves 15 bits to the left of the binary point, which can represent all integers less than 2<sup>15</sup> = 32768, as you have experimentally determined.

However, there are some numbers higher than this threshold that still have an error less than 0.001.  As Eric Postpischil pointed out in his comment, all `float64` values between 32768.0 and 32768.001 (the largest being exactly 32768+137438953/2<sup>37</sup>), which the `float32` conversion rounds down to exactly 32768.0, meet your accuracy requirement.  And of course, any number that happens to be exactly representable in a `float32` will have no representation error.

Comment: 32768 is not the maximum, though; all `float64` up to 32768.0009999999965657480061054229736328125 in magnitude round to a `float32` less than .001 away.