how can i get the value that is displayed when printing a np.float32 value as float? (or int)
I am loading an openEXR files that I have rendered int values into.
Of course they are stored as float32 internally, which can/will cause issues.
But here i am a bit stumped.
When I load the values, and print them, they look like this:
72840000000.0
This is basically what i need, just need to get the integer part of it.
But I cant seam to make that happen:
num loaded from .exr PRINTED AS 72840000000.0
to reproduce:
num = np.float32(72840000000.0)

int(num)
> 72840003584

round(num)
> 72840003584

float(num)
> 72840003584.0

np.float64(num)
> 72840003584.0

etc. etc.
I understand that internally the float is not exactly the printed value, and i dont need it to be. I just want the number that is printed as an integer.
int(float(str(num)))
> 72840000000

this actually works but it leads to physical pain and i cannot commit to this.
Is there a way to get the correct value?
Because I am rendering the values directly from blender into the openEXR, I cannot choose as which type it is stored.
But I could split the integer into 3 float32 and store them into seperate channels to get more prescision. but this all seams a bit insane.
How can I solve this?
Stage 2
I implemented the way using string representation, and ran into a brand new issue:
num = np.float32(97729856.)
num_arr = np.array([num, num])
print(num_arr)
> [97729856.]

print(num)
> 97729860.0

Or another way to demonstrate:
num_array[0]
Out[50]: 97729860.0
num_array[0:1]
Out[51]: array([97729856.], dtype=float32)

So it seams the representation is different when the value is in a np array as when it is not. even though its the same data type.
The string representation trick to get to my int does not work here anymore (even when i work in an array)
ids
Out[22]: 
array([97729856., 97731936.,], dtype=float32)
ids.astype(str)
Out[23]: 
array(['97729860.0', '97731940.0',], dtype='<U32')
ids.astype(str).astype(float)
Out[24]: 
array([97729860., 97731940.,])
ids.astype(str).astype(float).astype(np.uint64)
Out[25]: 
array([97729860, 97731940, ],
      dtype=uint64)

So it seams while it displays the value i need when printing the array, when casting it will use the... other representation.
So I am still not able to get the value that is displayed in a variable

I cannot reproduce. In my computer num = 72840000000.0 followed by int(num)  gives 72840000000 as result

@Elerium115 you should be able to reproduce if you make num a 32-bit float in the first place - try num = np.float32(72840000000.0)

@pho thanks, but then the question should be modified so the example is reproducible

@Elerium115 edited it, mybad

This is an inherent issue with using 32-bit floats where they do not have enough precision to represent the numbers you want to represent. Your idea to split the number into multiple smaller numbers is a good one, as is converting the string representation. Note that you can simply do int(str(num)) instead of having to convert the string to float and then to int. Can you elaborate on why this approach is undesirable?

@pho it just seams unclean to use the string representation as a tool. I feel like there must be a better way doing this.
But if there isnt I just might, I thought it is really strange that the int conversion and the string representation are so far from another. And the int() conversion directly does not work with the dot in the str representation: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0'"

The other option is to note that you effectively only have 6 or if lucky 7 good decimal digits after converting  a float32 into an integer. Rounding it so that the trailing zeroes are restored is every bit as unclean but might still be what you want if you already have data stored in this format with a lot of trailing zeroes. Anything else doubles your storage requirements.

@MartinBrown in most cases I will not have trailing zeros.
but the stringn representation trick also did not work. am editing the question now

The fundamental issue here is that if you want to store integers like 72840000000, type float32 is simply not the right tool for the job.  Unfortunately that number is also too big for an unsigned 32-bit integer.  So storing as a string, or as a pair of 32-bit integers, aren't bad options.

@SteveSummit I actually dont need to store integers that big, but  up to 10Mrd would be good. I just pumped up the numbers to be sure. But the core issue is that i do not have a say in the data type. I can only render into floats in blender as far as i know.
as said before, splitting the int into 3 parts that survive float could be done.
but then again. When python is perfectly able to print the correct value every time. why is it seamingly impossible to get this printed value into an integer?

@Marcel My answer, which I concede may be unsatisfying, is that for most data types, including float, how it displays is quite often significantly different from what it is.  When you try to store the value 72840000000 into a float32, the value actually stored is 72840003584, which in binary has 24 bits of precision and is an exact multiple of 2¹³ or 8192.  When you print it back out, Python helpfully rounds it back to 72840000000, but that's an approximation.  Internally it's still 72840003584, and when you convert it to an integer, that's the value that's converted.

@SteveSummit Yes i totally understand, and thats fine. It can do that. I just need some way to actually retrieve the displayed value, because for my usecase, that is good enough.
It seams i can iterate over the np array, cast every element seperate into str, then float, then int, to accomplish my goal (because for some reason casting the whole array to str will lead to OTHER RESULTS). Its super duper odd.
this even happens on much smaller numbers below 100mil (I understand this is still a high number)

As long as your integers are less than or equal to 2²⁴ = 16777216, you can store them in a float32 without loss of precision.

@Marcel Sorry if I'm telling you things you already know.  I'm here because of the floating-point tag; I don't know enough about Python to help you with your conversions.

@SteveSummit alright thats very good to know.
sadly my pointclouds have a lot more points. but i can possibly divide the index below this value somehow.
how many decimal points are accurate with float32? or where can i read up on that?
If I divide my indices by 100000 before saving, and multiplying again on load, can i get around that?

@SteveSummit I am super thankful for your input, if my comment seamed defensive, it should not have been!

No worries!  And dividing by 10…00 before saving is something I was going to suggest.  Roughly: float32 gives you about 7 digits of precision, although this is not an exact value.  But that's why the number 72840003584 departs in the 8th digit.  (In fact you can safely store all 7-digit integers, and 8-digit integers up to 16777216.)

okay wow, by using this 8 digit value i dont have any precision left anymore for decimal points.. right? I tried to understand this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71649956/5719743 but i am a bit lost.
If not I could just shift the indices by dividing with 10*x to gain some prescision.
If that does not work, i could modulu with 16777216 and use a second channel that stores the integer division of index / 16777216, and so on... making my exr file huge in the process haha
but getting back to the devide by 10*n would this gain me something? or would i get inprecision again??

Could you tell us why you're trying to do this in the first place? If it's for display purposes, then it doesn't seem useful to try to go through an int - you're going to display a string, not an int. (You don't need to use int to remove the .0, if that's why you were doing this.) On the other hand, if it's for doing math, then there shouldn't be a reason to couple your math to NumPy's float stringification logic.

@user2357112 The values  are indices of points in a pointcloud, that i render out in blender. I need a direct mapping of pixel to point.
The values are then used as indices. I dont need to represent them, just for all my tests, the representation was point on, and the cast was not.
I am aware that there would have been values where the representation was off, but thats fine, i would  have been okay with a few wrong values.

Is that an artifact of how you wrote your tests, or are you saying that in your actual use case, any large integers you work with are overwhelmingly likely to end in a bunch of zeros?

If your actual values are overwhelmingly likely to end in zeros, then you should be happy that your "stage 2" efforts gave you 97729860 instead of 97729856, as 97729860 would be much more likely to appear in your actual input.

@user2357112 the values are sequential. so its actually very unlikely to end in a lot of zero values

Then what you're trying to do isn't going to help you. Almost all of your large values are going to be wrong either way. This is just going to change which of them are wrong.

I could just shift the indices by dividing with 10^x to gain some precision. Well, no, not quite.  In doing that it's more like you're shifting the precision around.  Type float32 has 24 bits of precision, period — but the question is, which set of values can be represented exactly, and which can't?  By default, the representable numbers all involve powers of 2, not powers of 10.  But if you pre-scale by 10^X (using a type with enough precision to do so), you would be arranging that it'd be powers of 10 that are exactly representable.

If you truly need more than 24 bits of precision, then yes, breaking into two halves (using division and modulus) is the appropriate course of action.

Are you sure you have to use floats? The OpenEXR documentation says the format supports 32-bit UINT channels, which would be much more appropriate for your use case.

@SteveSummit I think i finally understood!
Yes you are right, i would have just moved the issue somewhere else.
I am currently trying to split my values into multiple floats.
I think i actually already ran into an implicit cast in blender, that already cost me the needed precision. I am stepping back thourgh my code and split it early enoug.
its not just 2 flots where one is  n % n^24 and the other is n // n^24
Thank you guys very much!
|if any of you want to forumulate this into an answer, i would be happy to set it is answer. if not, i will try to get around to writing it ty!!

@user2357112 Yeah i read that too, but i cant set the export to uint. also i cant really chose the types in blender  much

I think you understand this, but to be clear: if you used a raw float32, any of the numbers 72840000000, 72840000001, or 72840000002 would all map to 72840003584, which is not what you want.  Now, if you did an integer division by 100000, stored in a float32, and multiplied it by 100000 again on the way out, you'd find that 72840000000, 72840000001, and 72840000002 would all map to 72840000000, which is closer to what it sounds like you want — except you still wouldn't be able to distinguish them, because they'd all map to 72840000000.

Looking at the Blender docs... yeah, looks like Blender can't take advantage of OpenEXR's UINT support. "Images higher than 8 bits per channel will be converted into a float on loading into Blender."

Looks like using more channels is the way to go.

What control do you have over the end doing the writing of the data file? One option which might work is to fib about the data format and tell it that your integer data record is reals. That will mean some very high values with top byte 0xff will be Nan encodings which might cause trouble. The other easy option is to rescale your integer output to be in the range 0-16777216 as @steveSummit suggested. It might also be possible to devise a convoluted way to convert into floats for output in such a way that most are chosen so that they are the integer representation of your original data.

I'm a bit mystified by your Stage 2 example with 97729856.0 That value has a canonical representation of 1527029 x 64 or in hexadecimal where it is easier to see
0x174cf5 x 2^6 which is 21 bits in the mantissa and should fit comfortably into a float32 without any issues.

What exact range of integer values represented can you actually live with if push comes to shove? I can find a way to encode signed integers up to 255x2^23 = 2139095040 in a single real in such a way that the decoding end can treat them as if they were integers. This is 255 wider dynamic range than naieve encoding but is it enough? The chunk that is missing are reserved for NaNs and Inf's by the IEEE754 standard.
